# How do I set an expiry date for each asset's cache in my website?

Tags: html, caching, http-headers, meta-tags, cache-control

I've looked around the web for a while for the answer and found [this](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching?hl=en) among other things.

However, I have not found any insight on how to set a *specific and separate* expiry date for each asset (stylesheet, image, etc).

Using `<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=n">` within the `<head>` tag doesn't seem to produce the desired outcome, for Google's PageSpeed Insights still poorly scores my site for lack of cache control.

By the way, my site is pure HTML.

Comment: I don't know about <head> tags. But it can be accomplished by creating separate expiry date for each asset using .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [nayabbashasayed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4046770/nayabbashasayed) for pointing me in the right direction.

I created a .htaccess file and used the following code I found [here](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/cache-control.html).

```
# Check for files with the listed extensions
<filesMatch ".(css|jpg|png|gif|js|woff)$">
# If a file with any of the above extensions are found, set the maximum age for the asset in seconds
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
</filesMatch>
```

When the set amount of time has passed, the user will have to retrieve the asset from the server, disregarding what was previously cached for that file. Even more information can be found in the link I posted in the question (it's right [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching?hl=en), too).

EDIT:

To set the max-age for a specific file like I first asked for, use the `<IfModule>` tag in the .htaccess file. More information [here](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/leverage-browser-caching.html).

Comment: You are welcome. For my website I"ve created `.htaccess` entry for each asset. It's showing 95% optimization in google insights.